# Show the existence of a point satisfying this integral equation

Tags: integration

$f(x)$ integrable in $[0,1]$. Suppose there is $M>0$ such that for every $x \in [0,1]$, $f(x)\ge M.$

I need to prove the existence of a point $c \in [0,1]$ that makes
$$2\int_{0}^{c}{f(x)}dx=\int_{0}^{1}{f(x)}dx$$ Is there only one point that satisfies this equation?

Can you guide me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $H(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$.

Since $f(x)\ge M>0$, then $\int_0^1f(x)dx>0$. Thus $H(0)<0$ and $H(1)>0$. Moreover, from the integrability of $f$ we conclude that $H$ is continuous in $[0,1]$ and derivable in $(0,1)$. Therefore, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, there is $c\in(0,1)$ such that $H(c)=0$. That is $\int_0^cf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t$

But, by the differentiability, $H^\prime(x)=f(x)\ge M>0$. So $H$ is strictly increasing. Then, the $c$ is unique.